# Magento 2 is there any way to add site url in admin wysiwyg editor

Tags: magento2, admin, url, wysiwyg

I am just want to put the site url in the admin wysiwyg editor. So I have search the site url like we use the `{{view url=""}}` in the admin.

Please suggest if anyone have used the site url in the admin wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Use `{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}` or `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}`. There is "Insert Variable" option in Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}` or 
`{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}`

There is already "Insert Variable" option in Editor. You can also use it as well.

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-add-variables-magento-2-templates/

Comment: Most welcome @mageDev0688